# Trying to combine videos losslessly with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i am trying to create bath that would automatically join multiple videos that are in folder (liimattavat) and that would make them to .ts files in (roska) and after that it would just combine them all without quality loss to (valmis.mp4)
but i dont seem to get it working as i get something like path doesn't exist

```
@echo off

for %%a in ("liimattavat\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i %%a -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "roska\%%~na.ts"
for %%a in ("roska\*.ts") do "concat:"roska\*.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc valmis.mp4
pause
```

sorry if i was confusing, please ask me if you need more specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you why it doesn't work, it's because `ffmpeg` expects `-i ...` for every input argument. Ie, `-i path1 -i path2 -i path3`. You're only writing one `-i` then dumping your list of files afterwards.

An easy alternative is to write your list to a text file, one line per file name, and then pass that file to `ffmpeg` using `-i` like you did.

[You can read more here.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem,
here is code that i used:
'@echo off
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy merged.mp4
pause'

Comment: Sounds good! I generally use it from a C# application, so I can write the `-i ...` syntax properly, but from a Windows batch file you're pretty much SOL there.